# Tesseract index >= 0 && index < size_used_:Error:Assert failed Error

Tags: tesseract

I successfully wrote the traineddata file for a new tesseract language, but when I was finished, I continue to get the following error:

`index >= 0 && index < size_used_:Error:Assert failed:in file ../ccutil/genericvector.h, line 657`

However, this even happens when I run tesseract on an image I trained with! I am confused as to what is going on, as I would expect that the error should not occur if I run tesseract on the training set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error indicates your training failed => you overlooked some error message during training.

Comment: Would an incorrect font_properties file cause this error? I didn't get any error messages and as far as I know, no error messages were printed.

Answer (score 4):

This error is being caused to the lack of a `lang.shapetable` file in your `lang.traineddata` file.

---

Make sure that you generate the shapetable:

```
shapeclustering -F font_properties -U unicharset lang.font.exp0.box.tr
```

This will create a file named `shapetable`. You will need to rename this to `lang.shapetable` before you can combine everything:

```
combine_tessdata lang.
```